# How to get the result base on both date table max values with different where condition and group by field name containing apostrophe?

Tags: sql-server

This is a query I need to fix:

```
Select I'd ,
       (select max(date) from mytablename where anothercolumn='1100' ) as  date1,
       max(date) as date2
from my tablename
group by I'd.
```

I am using this code but there only date2 column and comes proper and date1 columns ans not come proper date2 columns max date print with all rows

Comment: "*`Select I'd`*" and "*`group by I'd`*"? I have no idea what that second second sentence is attempting to say.

Comment: Can you provide a example of data set of the source and how you expect it to come back out in the end?  Also what version of SQL-Server are you running on?

Comment: Do you really have a column named I'd???? If so just wrap that in square brackets. [I'd] and then strongly reconsider that name.

Comment: Why do you have a collumn name with an `'`?

Comment: Whose smart idea is it to create a column with `'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with fields containing apostrophes like

```
Select [I'd]...
```

as about gathering different maximum dates for the same `[I'd]` you will need to do something like this:

```
select t1.[I'd]
from (select [I'd], max(date) from tablename where anothercolumn='1100' group by [I'd]) t1
outer join (select [I'd], max(date) from tablename where yetanothercolumn='1200' group by [I'd]) t2
on t1.[I'd] = t2.[I'd]
```